# How to open another pyqt gui and retrieve value from it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am working on developing a file selection dialog using Python 3.6 and pyqt5. The basic idea of the dialog is that it has the option to preview files before selecting. It can preview any kinds of registered windows files. The design was done using QtDesigner MainWindow.
Now I can open this preview file browser from another pyqt/python3 file. But how can I retrieve the selected filename and file path from that script?
Here is the test file where I am opening the preview browser file:

```
class TestBrowser(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self,browser):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  # This is defined in design.py file automatically
        # It sets up layout and widgets that are defined
        self.browser=browser
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.dario)

    def dario(self):
        self.browser.exec_()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    browser=bd.BrowserDialog()
    main=TestBrowser(browser)
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':    # if we're running file directly and not importing it
    main()
```

Comment: I had to do this once and my stupid approach was to store the value temporarily in a database or a global var. It works, but I only suggest it as a temporary fix. Or you

Comment: I had tried using setting central widget, trying to set dock widget. I also saw about python signals and events but just not sure how to do them

Comment: As long as your browser is written on python or lets you store the selected file name, you can just use any of the 2 answers I gave you. But honestly I fail to see why would you use a browser instead of a Qfiledialog. After all, the Qfiledialogs let you preview every file easily.

Comment: Why do you need two scripts when you can do everything you need in one calling the filebrowser?

Comment: I'm trying to preview files like doc, docx, pdf, ppt, pptx, odt, odf, csv, wav, mp3, amr, aac, ogg, jpg, png, gif, tif, dat, dll, ini and many others before selecting them @Saelyth. I'm not sure using QFileDialog I can do that.

Comment: Maybe not with all of them. You'd have to manually check which ones and wich ones not, but it's worth to try. On windows I usually just check this little button and it works fine for pictures/.doc/.docx files: http://prntscr.com/gaek4n (Note: that screenshot is after clicking on a Qfiledialog)

Answer (score 0):

I personally use globals on a different .py file (for sanity purposes) for stuff like this when I get stuck on "how can I move a value from another class/function/something".

**On new .py file:**

```
file_name = None
file_path = None

# Save function
def save_filename(selected_file, selected_path):
    global file_name, file_path
    file_name = selected_file
    file_path = selected_path
```

**And on your browser when you select a file, add:**

```
mynewpyfile.save_filename(file, path)
```

**Then from your main window you can get the file data as:**

```
self.pushTestbutton.clicked.connect(self.do_something)

def do_something(self):
    print("the selected file is" + mynewpyfile.file_path + "/" + mynewpyfile.file_name)
```

**Other alternatives:** http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html
In this approach you just add a QlineEdit and... athough limited, it can't be easier than this.

```
self.lineTest.setText(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()[0])
```

Comment: Thanks. From you I got an idea, though scrapped. Basically I'm trying to preview files like doc, docx, pdf, ppt, pptx, odt, odf, csv, wav, mp3, amr, aac, ogg, jpg, png, gif, tif, dat, dll, ini and many others inside filedialog before selecting them. So now I'm opening the file browser GUI, then from there after I preview and select a file, I copy its path, and then paste it to my main window.